# How can i make fit my products image within the image box

Tags: magento-1.9

When i import my images, its not fit to image box, how can i make fit for image box, for new products.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**For Magento 1**

Let's read the official documentation here : http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-image-size-type.html

**For Magento 2:**

You can change the product image size (ratio) in your theme.

app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/etc/view.xml

You are able to set different size for different location.

For example :

```
<image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image">
    <width>240</width>
    <height>300</height>
</image>
<image id="category_page_list" type="small_image">
    <width>240</width>
    <height>300</height>
</image>
```

You need to have the same ratio for all of your product image.

If your product image ratio :
- crop image to change ratio
- use css in your custom theme
- create a module to manage different ratio

Comment: The image isn't enlarged and cropped, it's just resized to fit inside the box set in view.xml. In OP's case, he get horizontal letterboxing. He needs his image to be enlarged, with its left and right side cut off.